# How to upload any changes from file project to server?

Tags: laravel, server, ftp

how upload any change on laravel project to laravel project on server , I used Application named ( Transmit ) , but don't know if this app support something like this .
without using git

So any suggestions ??

Image : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why is git not an option?

I recommend initing a repo of your project, for instance to bitbucket.

You commit and push your project (watch some tutorial if you have never done that before).

After that you could ssh into your dev machine and pull that project, most likely from the master branch.

If you make any changes locally to that project you can use git to commit and push those changes, afterwards you ssh into your machine and git pull the latest state of the repository.

I also recommened following tool by the laravel author https://forge.laravel.com, this makes it really easy to handle the management.

Comment: I don't want to repo my project to github I want to upload him direct to my server :)